# Facebook auth api callback access token

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am accessing [facebook's api via](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) this url as I need to do manual login for the users:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&scope=publish_actions&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4004/auth/callback
```

I get the popup for authentication without a problem, give fb access and then my `callback` url is accessed with the url:

```
http://localhost:4004/?login#_=_
```

Normally I would expect an access token so I could post on the users behalf.

I'm writing my code in node and using the [node npm fb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) package to help me post

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you also need to tell facebook what you would like returned add this as one of the query parameters:

```
 response_type=token
```

Then you'll get back the token in the url

**complete url**

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123456&scope=publish_actions&redirect_uri=http://localhost:4004/auth/callback&response_type=token
```